# Select array where values

Tags: php, arrays

i have a value array like this , how to only showing array where companyID like $companyID

```
$price = array { 
            [0]=>{ 
                ["Price"]=>"5000" 
                ["leadTime"]=>"2" 
                ["companyID"]=>"1" 
            } 
            [1]=>{ 
                ["Price"]=>"4400" 
                ["leadTime"]=>"2" 
                ["companyID"]=>"2" 
            } 
            [2]=>{ 
                ["Price"]=>"3000" 
                ["leadTime"]=>"2" 
                ["companyID"]=>"3" 
            } 
        }
```

if the $companyID=1 the result like this

```
$price = array { 
            [0]=>{ 
                ["Price"]=>"5000" 
                ["leadTime"]=>"2" 
                ["companyID"]=>"1" 
            } 
        }
```

Comment: `$price = array_filter($price, function ($v) use ($companyID) {
    return $v['companyID'] ==$companyID;
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use php built in [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

```
$price = array { 
        [0]=>{ 
            ["Price"]=>"5000" 
            ["leadTime"]=>"2" 
            ["companyID"]=>"1" 
        } 
        [1]=>{ 
            ["Price"]=>"4400" 
            ["leadTime"]=>"2" 
            ["companyID"]=>"2" 
        } 
        [2]=>{ 
            ["Price"]=>"3000" 
            ["leadTime"]=>"2" 
            ["companyID"]=>"3" 
        } 
    } ;

$companyid = 1; 
$price = array_filter($price, function ($el) use ($companyid) { return ($el["companyID"] == $companyid); } );
```